# Regex match url without file extension

Tags: regex, replace, preg-match

I would like some help matching the following urls.

```
/settings => /settings.php
/657_46hallo => /657_46hallo.php
/users/create => /users.php/create
/contact/create/user => /contact.php/create/user
/view/info.php => /view.php/info.php
/view/readme - now.txt => /view.php/readme - now.txt
/ => [NO MATCH]
/filename.php => /unknown.php
/filename.php/users/create => /unknown.php
```

if the first part after the domain name is a filename ending with ".php"
(see last 2 examples) It should redirect to /unknown.php

I think I need 2 regular expressions
1st should be almost something like: ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(/)?(.*)?$
2nd to catch the direct filename "/filename.php" or "/filename.php/create/user"
so I can redirect to unknown.php

The 1st regular expression that I got almost works for the first part.
 ==============================================

```
request url: http://domain.com/user/create
regex: ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(/)?(.*)?$
replace http://domain.com/$1.php$2$3
makes: http://domain.com/user.php/create
```

Problem is it also matches http://domain.com/user.php/create

If someone could help me with both regular expressions that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match those `.php` cases you can try this:

```
^\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(\/)?(.*)?$
```

See here on [Regexr](http://regexr.com?2tt0g)

If you want to avoid those cases try this:

```
^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(?!\.php)(?:(/)(.*)|)$
```

See here on [Regexr](http://regexr.com?2tt0j)

The `(?!\.php)` is a negative look ahead that ensures that there is no `.php` at this place.

Comment: That seems like to do the trick. (The first example posted is different then from the regexr link, but the one on the regexr site is working: ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.php)(/)?(.*)?$)

Answer (score 1):

When all you have is a hammer...

While this probably *could* be solved with a regexp, it is probably the wrong tool for the job, unless you have constraints that MANDATE the use of regexps.

Split the string using '/' as the delimiter, see whether the first component ends with '.php'; if so, reject it, otherwise append '.php' to the first component and join the components back using '/'.

Comment: This is going to be used as a rewrite rule on the cherokee webserver. Cherokee webserver doesn't allow me to split the url, A programming language would indeed make it a lot easier, but that unfortunately isn't a optionn